# How do I set a pin on Current Location, use Pin as Geofence, alert user onEnter, then reset all / start over again?

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I'm a product designer trying to spin up a location-based reminder concept to validate a pretty early stage idea. I could prototype all of these screens in Figma, but real-time Location and a contextual alert are foundational to my hypothesis, so here I am pulling my hair out trying to accomplish this in SwiftUI

https://www.figma.com/proto/jxYwPbqe4oqsXBbf6CZDDi/Location-Reminder-Spec?page-id=0%3A1&node-id=1%3A189&viewport=161%2C384%2C0.12701110541820526&scaling=scale-down

I've been piecing this together from a variety of tutorials (Ray Wenderlich, Hacking Swift, Apple's Swift UI) and snippets about Location etc. but most of the tutorials have more objects and views and other stuff that I don't need which is complicating my scrappy MVP collage approach.

So far, I've got an MKMapView centered on my the coordinates of the User's Location and I've got my button displayed.

I'm wondering

- How to create a CLCircularRegion using the coordinates from user location?
- How to place a MKMapAnnotation on the Map using the coordinates from the user location and how to remove the annotation after pressing a button inside the notification?

With the above, I think I'll be able to sort out how to fire the notification and show the notification onEnter.

I've got 4 files in the project so far...

LocationManager.swift

```
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
        override init() {
                super.init()
                manager.delegate = self
                manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                manager.startUpdatingLocation()
        }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last.map{
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.coordinate.latitude, longitude: $0.coordinate.longitude),
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
            )
        }
    }
}

extension CLLocation {
    var latitude: Double {
        return self.coordinate.latitude
    }
    
    var longitude: Double {
        return self.coordinate.longitude
    }
}
```

ContentView.swift

```
import CoreLocation
import MapKit
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = LocationManager()
    @State private var locations = [MKPointAnnotation] ()
    
    
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        HStack {
            Text("Location Reminder")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .bold()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()

        ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
            Map(coordinateRegion: $manager.region,
                showsUserLocation: true)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            ReminderButton()
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

ReminderButton.swift

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ReminderButton: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
                Button(action: {
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    Text("Add a Reminder")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 0.2, x: 1, y: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an empty file that I've named **Geofence.swift** where I plan on creating a CLCircularRegion and setting up the notifications / alerts onEnter etc.

Appreciate any and all help / advice / suggestions. Also please LMK if there are ways to improve my post and/or if it belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
import CoreLocation
struct SingleLocationView: View {
    @StateObject var manager = LocationManager()
    @State private var locations = [PinnedLocation] ()
    @State var userTrackingMode: MapUserTrackingMode = .follow
    let radius: CGFloat = 160 //meters approx 0.1 miles
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack{
                    Text("Location Reminder")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                }
                Spacer()
                
            }
            .padding()
            
            ZStack (alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                GeometryReader{ geo in
                    Map(coordinateRegion: $manager.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $userTrackingMode, annotationItems: locations, annotationContent: { annotation in
                        MapAnnotation(coordinate: annotation.coordinate, anchorPoint: CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), content: {
                            //Use this vs Circle because your map is a rectangle circumference is an oval
                            //Maybe a stretched Circle could be a little more accurate
                            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                            
                                .overlay(
                                    Image(systemName: "mappin").foregroundColor(.red))
                            
                            // The screen vertical and horizontal multiplied by your radius divided Map vertial/horizontal span in meters
                                .frame(width: (geo.size.width/manager.regionSpanInLongitudeDeltaMeters.value) * radius, height: (geo.size.height/manager.regionSpanInLatitudeDeltaMeters.value) * radius, alignment: .center)
                            
                            
                        })
                    })
                    
                        .ignoresSafeArea()
                    
                }
                ReminderButton(locations: $locations).environmentObject(manager)
                    .padding()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SingleLocationView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SingleLocationView()
    }
}

//You MKAnnotaion is a Protocol you need to create your own class
//MKPointAnnotation is a MKShape for use with MKMapView
class PinnedLocation: NSObject, MKAnnotation, Identifiable{
    var title: String?
    var subtitle: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    init(title: String? = nil, subtitle: String? = nil, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.title = title
        self.subtitle = subtitle
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
    ///Get the CLCircularRegion with the given radius
    func getCLCircularRegion(radius: CGFloat) -> CLCircularRegion{
        CLCircularRegion(center: self.coordinate, radius: radius, identifier: "\(self.id)")
    }
}

extension UnitLength{
    //This is approx do research on degrees to meters
    static let degree = UnitLength(symbol: "degree", converter: UnitConverterLinear(coefficient: 111111))
}
class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion()
    //If you do it the way you were doing it get the most current location from here to append to your array
    @Published var lastLocation: CLLocation = CLLocation()
    ///Region gives span in degrees. This is a rough conversion
    var regionSpanInLatitudeDeltaMeters: Measurement<UnitLength>{
        Measurement(value: region.span.latitudeDelta, unit: UnitLength.degree).converted(to: .meters)
    }
    ///Region gives span in degrees. This is a rough conversion
    var regionSpanInLongitudeDeltaMeters: Measurement<UnitLength>{
        Measurement(value: region.span.longitudeDelta, unit: UnitLength.degree).converted(to: .meters)
    }
    private let manager = CLLocationManager()
    override init() {
        super.init()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        //Don't need it SwiftUI does this for you
        //manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        //manager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locations.last.map{
            region = MKCoordinateRegion(
                center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: $0.coordinate.latitude, longitude: $0.coordinate.longitude),
                span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.5, longitudeDelta: 0.5)
            )
        }
        lastLocation = locations.last!
        
    }
}

extension CLLocationCoordinate2D{
    var annotation: PinnedLocation{
        PinnedLocation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: self.latitude, longitude: self.longitude))
    }
}
struct ReminderButton: View {
    //The button joins your location manager with the locations displayed. It needs access to both
    @EnvironmentObject var manager: LocationManager
    @Binding var locations: [PinnedLocation]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                //Append the current center/location to your list of annotions
                locations.append(manager.region.center.annotation)
            }) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 40)
                    Text("Add a Reminder")
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(40)
                .shadow(color: .gray, radius: 0.2, x: 1, y: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```